# Find out column having maximum missing values using Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, missing-data

I'm new to Python. I want to find out which column in my dataframe has maximum missing values. let's say we have 5 rows 1000 columns.
For example

```
C1    C2    ...   C1000  
10    21    ...   NaN  
NaN   45    ...   29  
15    21    ...   NaN  
21    NaN   ...   27  
61    NaN   ...   NaN
```

C1000 has maximum missing values. So my code should return column name "C1000"

Answer (score 6):

You could use `df.count().idxmin()`. `df.count()` returns Series with number of non-NA/null observations. And, `idxmin` would give you column with most non-NA/null values.

```
In [12]: df
Out[12]:
     C1    C2  C1000
0  10.0  21.0    NaN
1   NaN  45.0   29.0
2  15.0  21.0    NaN
3  21.0   NaN   27.0
4  61.0   NaN    NaN

In [13]: df.count()
Out[13]:
C1       4
C2       3
C1000    2
dtype: int64

In [14]: df.count().idxmin()
Out[14]: 'C1000'
```